# Html.ActionLink as button not hyperlink

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, twitter-bootstrap

Cannot seem to find the code that relates to this implementation in VB but I have an action link which currently displays as a hyperlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = currentItem.CustomerId})
```

But would like it to be displayed as a button instead as am using twitter bootstrap and the buttons defined in the CSS look amazing. I know how to define a button link normally but how would I change the action link to one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the CSS class property to `btn`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = currentItem.CustomerId}, New With {.class = "btn"})
```

Comment: I'm not vb.net specialist, but I think it should look like that
 `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = currentItem.CustomerId}, New With {.class = "btn"})`

Comment: @NParks see the updated answer. I'm not familiar with vb.net syntax. Add the `class` attribute to the `htmlAttributes` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

you should do a extension method

```
public static class MVCExtensions
    {
public static string SubmitButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string buttonText)
        {
            return String.Format("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"{0}\" />", buttonText);
        }
}
```

then you call in code

```
@Html.SubmitButton("Save")
```